# Как сделать затемнение блока с текстом после открытия меню?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Есть меню на [jsfiddle.net/2zxjbxsf/](https://jsfiddle.net/2zxjbxsf/) Как можно сделать затемнение блока с текстом после открытия меню и убрать затемнение текста после закрытия меню ?

```
$("#showmenu").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#menu").toggleClass("show");
        });
        $("#menu a").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            if($(this).next('ul').length){
                $(this).next().toggle('fast');
                $(this).children('i:last-child').toggleClass('fa-caret-down fa-caret-left');
            }
});
```

Comment: "затмение меню с текстом" - это имеется ввиду текст самой страницы "притушить" надо?

Comment: @cyadvert Да вы правы, немного не так написал.

Comment: @cyadvert Спасибо работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте `CSS`

```
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); 
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

В `JS` после `$("#menu").toggleClass("show");` добавьте

```
if ($("#menu").hasClass('show')) {
    $('<div class="overlay">&nbsp;</div>').prependTo($('body'));
} else {
    $('.overlay').remove();
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2zxjbxsf/2/ я так понимаю для иконки меню, всё-таки надо использовать явно не jpg картинку, хотя бы png c прозрачностью, как вариант: сверстать в css или отрисовать svg

Comment: @Shilgen Да я знаю, я только для примера поставил картинку, чтобы не загружать щрифты с иконками.

Answer (score 3):

https://jsfiddle.net/r780bh5r/2/
добавьте саму затемнялку в конец

```
<div class="milk-shadow"></div>
```

css

```
.milk-shadow {
  position: fixed;
  top:0; right:0; left:0;
  height: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  transition: opacity: .5s;
}
#menu.show ~ .milk-shadow {height: 100%; opacity: .3;}
```

js - плюс в юзабилити - убираем меню при клике "в молоко"

```
$(document).on('click','.milk-shadow',function(){
    $("#showmenu").click();
});
```

Хозяйке на заметку - можно менять класс не у меню а у боди, тогда можно будет ещё допрописать у боди overflow:hidden чтобы он не скролился при открытом меню

Answer (score 2):

добавьте в `html`:

```
<div class="blackout"></div>
```

добавьте в `css`:

```
.blackout {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  z-index: 5;
  display: none;
}
```

и по открытию меню добавьте в скрипт `$(".blackout").css("display", "block");`, а по закрытию, соответственно, `$(".blackout").css("display", "none");`

Comment: Тоже хороший вариант, только нет проверки когда меню открыто, а когда закрыто. Не могу поставить плюсик так как нужно иметь 15 баллов репутации, но все равно спасибо.

Comment: @Denis благодарствую)