# Помогите сделать простой эффект с помощью jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, анимация

Хотелось бы сделать эффект затемнения
Сам суть: Есть два меню , одна из них не видна(display:none). так вот при наведении на первое меню, невидимое меню показывается на экране, и после этого фон затемняется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но не получается http://osiyo-nur.uz/osiyo-nur.uz/test6/.
Использую jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".none").css('display') == 'block') {
    $("#overlay").css('display', 'block');
  } else {
    $("#overlay").css('display', 'none');
  }

});
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
  width: 60%;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.block:hover+.none {
  display: block;
}

.block:hover .overlay {
  display: block;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GoodGross</title>

  <link href="css\style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background: #FAFAFA">
    <!-- HEADER PART STARTS -->
    <div class="main_content">
      <div class="test">
        <a class="btn btn-danger block">Block</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger none">None</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" id="overlay"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Хотелось бы чтобы когда показывался второй элемент появлялся эффект затемнения на всю страницу

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать затемнение блока с текстом после открытия меню?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482838/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e)

Answer (score 1):

Немного изменив ваш код в jquery, добавил действие .hover и функцию в него
Чтоб был заднии фон темный нужно для блока который будет находиться выше фона додать  position:relative; и z-index:99;

Результат можете посмотреть ниже

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.block').hover(function(){
   $(".overlay").css('display', 'block');
   $(".none").css('display', 'block');
 })
});
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
  width: 60%;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}
 .none{
 position:relative;
 z-index:99;
 }


.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GoodGross</title>

  <link href="css\style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background: #FAFAFA">
    <!-- HEADER PART STARTS -->
    <div class="main_content">
      <div class="test">
        <a class="btn btn-danger block">Block</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger none">None</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" id="overlay"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```